# Stop a While (True) with a signal

Tags: c, signals, wait

I'm working with concurrency in c, I have a proccess pool. to do this I have every children inside a While (True) loop. to kill the children I'm using a global variable and a signal Handler to modify it break the loop.

The problem is, the children use allocated memory and I want to free it. so, using a simple SIGTERM from the parent won't work.

GLOBAL:

```
int sigusr1_count = 0;

void SenalTerminacion() {
    ++sigusr1_count;
}

signal(SIGUSR1, SenalTerminacion);
```

CHILD:

```
While (1) {
    if (sigusr1_count != 0) {
        break;
    }
    /* some calculations */
}
print("Hola Stack Overflow\n");
/* freeing memory */ 
exit(0);
```

FATHER:

```
kill(pidChild, SIGUSR1);
wait(NULL);
```

If I comment out the line with the wait the code works and the message is displayed. but if I leave wait in the program hangs. I can imagine is the child not ending due to wierd stuff I don't know about signals and waits. I have n Children.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a requirement to use signals? You could use other IPCs, for instance pipes or unix domain sockets.

Comment: What do you mean by "allocated memory"? Just `malloc()` and `free()`? If so, you can just use `SIGTERM` as all that memory will be freed automatically when the OS cleans up the process.

Comment: I was doing that and valgrind was identifying memory leaks

Answer (score 2):

sigusr1_count is possibly cached (in the register file -- the compiler did this) by your child/parent process and not being read from memory (or compiled out completely as invariant in the child). Mark it as volatile to prevent both:

```
volatile int sigusr1_count=0;
```

Better: Consider using semaphores for interprocess signalling rather than your busy while(1) loop.

Comment: Did you try signalling between the processes using semaphores rather than the busy loop? If you want a busy loop, try atomics otherwise it's hard for me to predict what the compiler will do with your references to the global.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal handler function has the wrong signature.  It must accept one argument of type `int`, in which it will receive the signal number that it is called to handle.  It doesn't need to *use* the value so provided, but it does need to declare the parameter.

As originally posted, your signal handler function implementation was also wrong.  It performed an `exit(0)`, which is OK in itself, but which would have prevented your child processes from doing any cleanup after they handled the signal, except in exit handler functions.  In particular, they would never have been able to reach the `print()` call.

I cannot explain exactly what's happening when you try to terminate the process's children, but my best guess is that they are not receiving the signal, therefore when the parent tries to `wait()`, it hangs indefinitely waiting for a child to exit that never is going to do.

There is an outside possibility that your signal handler having the wrong signature results in unexpected behaviour when the handler is called.  It is in any event true that the whole program exhibits undefined behaviour as a result of calling the `signal()` function with an incompatible argument.

In any case, if you get a message printed only when you comment out the `wait()` call then it is probably generated by the parent process.

Comment: I have a print inside the signal and the code in it is being excecuted.